# What's the best way to animate (simple shapes) in response to touches?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, core-animation, core-graphics

I have a custom `UIView` on which I would like to show simple animated shapes in response to touches. For instance:

- whenever the user taps the screen a circle appears, with an animation, under the finger
- if the user ends touching the circle should disappear with an animation
- if the user reaches a certain part of the screen the circle should increase its size (smoothly)

What I am doing now (*see code below*) is to use `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, etc to have a set with all the touches. Then in `drawRect` I draw a circle for each of the touches. Everything is super static.

What is the best way to animate?

Thanks!

PS: for completeness here is part of my code

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    for (UITouch *touch in ts) { //ts is the set with all touches
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(location.x-circleSize/2, location.y-circleSize/2+correctionY,
                                          circleSize*1.15, circleSize*1.15);
        CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
        /* etc etc */
    }
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ 
    /* etc etc */
    ts = [[NSMutableSet setWithSet: [event touchesForView:self]] retain];
    /* etc etc */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using drawRect in your main view, I would create a new subview for each object. Those subviews could be UIImageViews, or standard UIViews that you then continue to draw by subclassing the subview's drawRect.

Then, it would be trivial to animate those subviews using UIView's animation methods:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^(void) {
                     // Do something to the view...
                 }];
```

Clearly you'd then need to add code to manage the touches and remove the subviews when needed, but that shouldn't be too onerous.

Comment: I'm implementing it right now, I'll report back soon. Any advice on how to easily keep track of which touch is which across `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`...? Thanks

Comment: The object instances remain the same so you can key on the addresses.  See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW14

Comment: Great! I'm trying now to implement what you have advised but I guess I need to do some reading before I understand how animations work.

Comment: A question on the philosophy... Are animations usually handled out of the animated UIView? Do they usually involve property of the entire UIView (alpha, size, etc) rather than property of a specific part of the UIView (the color of one of the elements, for instance)? Thanks

Comment: You can animate many properties of any view or subview thereof.

Comment: May I ask if it is possible animate a custom property (eg: line width) with `animateWithDuration `? As far as I've read on the internet it is not possible, but I might have missed something. Thanks.